# Prove that the functions is of the form "$cx$".

Tags: calculus

If $f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Suppose

$f(x)= \frac{1}{t}\int_0^t(f(x+y)-f(y))dy$

for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $t>0$. Then show that there exists a constant $c$ such that $f(x)=cx$ for all $x$.

Comment: Hint: you have to prove that $f'(x)$ is constant. If you still don't know how to begin, I can tell you more :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By changing the variable we have

$$tf(x)=\int_x^{x+t}f(u)du-\int_0^tf(y)dy=\int_t^{x+t}f(y)dy-\int_0^xf(y)dy$$
so by differentiating with respect to $x$ we get for all $t$
$$tf'(x)=f(x+t)-f(x)$$
and by differentiating with respect to $t$ we get for all $x$
$$f'(x)=f'(x+t)$$
so finally  for $x=0$ we ge $f'(0)=c=f'(t)$ and then $f(t)=ct+c'$ and clearly $f(0)=0$.